# Floating Point Exception with Numpy and PyTables

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, pytables

I have a rather large HDF5 file generated by PyTables that I am attempting to read on a cluster. I am running into a problem with NumPy as I read in an individual chunk. Let's go with the example:

The total shape of the array within in the HDF5 file is,

```
In [13]: data.shape
Out[13]: (21933063, 800, 3)
```

Each entry in this array is a `np.float64`.

I am having each node read slices of size `(21933063,10,3)`. Unfortunately, NumPy seems to be unable to read all 21 million subslices at once. I have tried to do this sequentially by dividing up these slices into 10 slices of size `(2193306,10,3)` and then using the following reduce to get things working:

```
In [8]: a = reduce(lambda x,y : np.append(x,y,axis=0), [np.array(data[i*      \
        chunksize: (i+1)*chunksize,:10],dtype=np.float64) for i in xrange(k)])
In [9]:
```

where `1 <= k <= 10` and `chunksize = 2193306`. This code works for `k <= 9`; otherwise I get the following:

```
In [8]: a = reduce(lambda x,y : np.append(x,y,axis=0), [np.array(data[i*      \
        chunksize: (i+1)*chunksize,:10],dtype=np.float64) for i in xrange(k)])
Floating point exception
home@mybox  00:00:00  ~
$
```

I tried using Valgrind's `memcheck` tool to figure out what is going on and it seems as if PyTables is the culprit. The two main files that show up in the trace are `libhdf5.so.6` and a file related to `blosc`.

Also, note that if I have `k=8`, I get:

```
In [12]: a.shape
Out[12]: (17546448, 10, 3)
```

But if I append the last subslice, I get:

```
In [14]: a = np.append(a,np.array(data[8*chunksize:9*chunksize,:10],   \
         dtype=np.float64))
In [15]: a.shape
Out[15]: (592192620,)
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what to do? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error that you get when directly reading the data into a numpy array? I would suggest that you preallocate your destination array instead of trying to build it up by appending multiple arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to allocate such a big array before (like DaveP suggests)?

```
In [16]: N.empty((21000000,800,3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: array is too big.
```

This is on 32bit Python.
You would actually need 20e6*800*3*8/1e9=384 GBytes of memory!
One Float64 needs 8 bytes.
Do you really need the whole array at once?

Sorry, did not read post properly.

Your array with k=8 subslices is already about 4.1 GByte big. Maybe that is the problem?

Does it work if you use only *8* instead of *10* for the last dimension?

Another suggestion, i would try first to resize the array, then fill it up:

```
a = zeros((4,8,3))
a = resize(a, (8,8,3))
a[4:] = ones((4,8,3))
```